# Activity regularizer with softmax?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras

I have an l1 activity_regularizer=l1 in the final layer of my generative neural network:

```
outputs = Dense(200, activation='softmax', activity_regularizer=l1(1e-5))(x)
```

It makes my results better but I don't understand why it would change anything for a softmax activation. The sum of outputs = 1 , with all positive values always so the regularizer should give exactly the same loss no matter what.

What is the `activity_regularizer=l1(1e-5)` doing in my training ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the Softmax, the contribution of the L1-Regularization to the total cost is in fact constant.

However, the **gradient of the regularization term is non-zero** and equals to the number of non-zero activations (gradient of *abs* is *sign*, so we have a sum of *sign*s of activations that are positive due to the softmax).

You can try to run with and without the L1-term and check how many non-zero elements you end up with.

Comment: So it penalizes the number of non-zeros. This would explain my output. In this case with all positive outputs, the gradient will be a constant for each update?

Comment: Assuming all outputs are consistently non-zero, the gradient term (from the regularizer) would always be the same (I don't think the word "constant" is appropriate, as it implies that it doesn't depend on the inputs, which is not true). However, L1 regularization usually results with some of the outputs being pushed to zero, and would consequently decrease the gradient term.

Comment: It's not constant, yes.